# How do I handle response from an Ajax Request in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a CRUD application set up in Ruby on Rails 3 - its working as is. I need to add some ajax here. My first requirement is to retrieve a customised form when clicking on a New Form link. This is the link I have at this point:

```
<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path(:subject_id=>@subject.id), :remote=>true %>
```

For my controller I've made the following adjustment to the new book action:

```
def new
    @book = Book.new
    if params[:subject_id].to_i >0 then
      @book.subject_id = params[:subject_id]
    end

    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @book }
        render :layout => false, :file=>'app/views/books/_form'
        return false
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @book }
      end
    end
  end
```

I checked in firebug and clicking on the link generated returns the form html  however I have no idea how to handle the response? Please do help.

Comment: You have to handle the response with JavaScript. How does your Ajax part looks like? Can you add the code ...?

Comment: Well all I've done is add a :remote parameter - is there more? I'm a total newbie to rails here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of responding with HTML respond with .js

Inside your .js.erb file could be something like this

```
$("#idname").append(<%= render "form" %>)
```

That way it renders and returns the form HTML but also gives the js code to append the HTML.

Comment: I haven't set up an erb js file? I'm quite new to rails 3. Where would I set this up.

Comment: Plus in php I'd normally enclose my html and any other variables in a json encoded object and handle the data in the response handler in javascript. How can this be emulated in ruby on rails - or is there a better way to do it. Is it a good idea to return raw html in an ajax query?

Comment: Well, not sure there is a right and a wrong way, I've seen pretty reputable sources go both routes.  And I'm sorry I meant .js.erb so it compiles the ruby before delivering the js.

Comment: And to get the js back add format.js to the respond to block and add a file to the view folder

Comment: Named after the action being called with the extension .js.erb

Comment: Got it - made a js.erb file for the action - works fine now!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly rely on Rails generated JavaScript, but I always like to have "more control" over my JavaScript code. In e.g. jQuery you could have something like this (**untested**), if you want to insert the partial (html) rendered by your controller into the site:

```
$("#new-book-button").click( function () {
  $.get('books/new', function(data) {
    $('#some-form-container').html(data);
  });
}
```